# Magento 2: Products not showing in search but in catalog is ok

Tags: magento2, catalog, products, search, magento2.2.9

I have a problem with my catalog. Products are visible in catalog category view pages (I can do any action - add to cart, buy...) but when I want to search any product then not showing in search results page.

Products have set `Visibility` as `Catalog,Search`

I reindex all indexees by `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command, `clean` and `flush` cashes but still products are not visible in catalog search page.

Can someone have any idea why its happening ?

Magento version: 2.2.9

Comment: IS their any error during re-indexing process ?

Comment: Hi, no, everything is ok